# Complete a suggested action automatically in Bash

Tags: bash

Sometimes your bash prompt suggests actions for you.

Like:

```
The program 'htop' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt-get install htop
```

Or:

```
the branch has no upstream branch yet, do git push --set-upstream origin branchname
```

Is there a command or shortcut or substitution for directly doing such a suggested action, without copying or retyping the code (like `!!` is a substitution for the last command)?

Comment: Even if there were, would you want to blindly do (as root!) whatever your computer told you to do?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the examples you gave are not the same thing. Under Ubuntu, the [Command Not Found Magic is explained here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CommandNotFoundMagic). To add some more detail, it's actually a Python script found in `/usr/lib/command-not-found`.

Here's an example:

```
# /usr/lib/command-not-found htop
The program 'htop' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt-get install htop
```

In `/etc/bash.bashrc`, included by the Bash shell at startup, we define the command-not-found handler:

```
# if the command-not-found package is installed, use it
if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found -o -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
        function command_not_found_handle {
                # check because c-n-f could've been removed in the meantime
                if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
                   /usr/lib/command-not-found -- "$1"
                   return $?
                elif [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
                   /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found -- "$1"
                   return $?
                else
                   printf "%s: command not found\n" "$1" >&2
                   return 127
                fi
        }
fi
```

Bash [version 4+ uses `command_not_found_handle`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver4.html) as a built-in name for handling situations where a command is not found.

> There is a new builtin error-handling function named `command_not_found_handle`.
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash4
>
> command_not_found_handle ()
> { # Accepts implicit parameters.
>   echo "The following command is not valid: \""$1\"""
>   echo "With the following argument(s): \""$2\"" \""$3\"""   # $4, $5 ...
> } # $1, $2, etc. are not explicitly passed to the function.
>
> bad_command arg1 arg2
>
> # The following command is not valid: "bad_command"
> # With the following argument(s): "arg1" "arg2"
> ```

So, the short answer, is no, there's no way to do what you're asking, without parsing the output and creating some kind of new functionality.